# Не получается ввод(С++)

Tags: c++

Всем привет, вот решаю задачу. Почему то после ввода имени аптеки, дальше ничего не происходит :с
А там дальше ввод таблеток , цен и тд идет
Вот вообщем задача, мой код и что выводит. Помогите пожалуйста

Мой код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;
struct Drug {
    string name;
    int price;
    string date;
};
struct Pharacy {
    string name;
    int count;
    Drug* drugs;
};
struct City {
    string name;
    int count;
    Pharacy* pharacy;
};
int main() {
    int N;
    cin >> N;
    City* city = new City[N];
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        cin >> city[i].name >> city[i].count;
        for (int j = 0; j < city[i].count; j++) {
            cin >> city[i].pharacy[j].name >> city[i].pharacy[j].count;
            for (int q = 0; q < city[i].pharacy[j].count; q++) {
                cin >> city[i].pharacy[j].drugs[q].name >> city[i].pharacy[j].drugs[q].price >> city[i].pharacy[j].drugs[q].date;
            }
        }
    }
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        cout << "City: " << city[i].name << endl;
        for (int j = 0; j < city[i].count; j++) {
            sum = 0;
            for (int q = 0; q < city[i].pharacy[j].count; q++) {
                sum += city[i].pharacy[j].drugs[q].price;
            }
            cout << "Average of " << city[i].pharacy[j].name << " is " << sum / city[i].pharacy[j].count << endl;
        }
    }
}
```

[image: задача]

[image: вот тут у меня код останавливается]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
City* city = new City[N]; как и это строка ты должен определить и Pharacy:           
for(int i = 0; i < N; i++)
{    
    city[i]->pharacy = new Pharacy;
    city[i]->pharacy->drugs = new Drug; 
}
в твоем варианте иы выходишь за рамки
```